# Can connections to ::1 be made reliable in Chromium?

Tags: chromium, ipv6

I just ran into this message from Chromium:

> The server at [::1] can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed.

I was trying to access `http://[::1]/`, which usually works. This is on an Ubuntu 14.04 system, where I just installed the latest security updates.

I don't know if the latest updates changed anything. I did however find out that it does work if my computer has a globally routable IPv6 address, but otherwise not.

Can Chromium be configured in a way where connections to ::1 will work reliably, even if I am on an IPv4-only network?

Comment: Sounds like you might have run into a bug in Chromium.

Comment: You shoudl try out `getent hosts ::1`.  You could also use `ip -6 add list` and use the scope link address as an IPv6 address alias for your machine in `/etc/hosts`.  And then your url would be `http://yourmachine/`.

Comment: @Anders The output from `getent hosts ::1` is `::1             ip6-localhost ip6-loopback`. I can connect to those names even while ::1 fails.

Comment: @Anders Adding a link-local address to `/etc/hosts` does not work. And I don't know where the interface specification would be expected to go in that case.

Comment: I found that if I create a routing table entry like this `ip -6 route add 2001:4860:4860::8888/128 dev eth0 src 2001:db8::1`, then Chrome will look at the source IP I specified, and it will work as long as the specified address is a native IPv6 address and fail if the specified address is a Teredo address. The destination of that routing entry has to match `2001:4860:4860::8888`, other IP addresses won't work. So that address must have been hardcoded in Chromium.

Comment: What does `getent hosts 2001:4860:4860::8888` give?  Isn't that Googles own DNS servers?  There are better sollutions for IPv6 than Teredo addresses.

Comment: @Anders You are right. That is Google's DNS server. But I am using a different DNS server, besides that particular workaround would completely break communication with `2001:4860:4860::8888`, but would make Chromium work. So clearly Chromium does not need to communicate with that IP. The out put from `getent hosts 2001:4860:4860::8888` is `2001:4860:4860::8888 google-public-dns-a.google.com`.

Comment: @Anders In this particular case I was only testing Teredo to figure out what worked and what did not. Actually there are cases, where Teredo is the best solution for IPv6 access, but in most cases Teredo is very unreliable. Teredo is unreliable when the native IPv6 end of the connection is relying on public relays. If the native IPv6 end of the connection has access to non-public relays Teredo can be very reliable. And in case the only connectivity accessible to the client is NAT4, then Teredo is the most reliable way to reach such a server.

Comment: I ran into the same problem after a certain Chrome update on both Windows 8 and Linux Mint so it isn't Ubuntu-specific... am sticking to Firefox for development for now.